# Airflow trigger tasks only based on previous runs status

Tags: airflow, airflow-scheduler

Is there a way to trigger the next task based on previous task run states. Scenario as below:

- Task1 - First task in m DAG
- Task2 - Run task2 only when task1 has succeeded
- Task3 - Run task 3 only when task3 has succeeded
- Task4 - Run task 4 only when task1 has run more than 10 hours(SLA missed)

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You have multiple options here:

1. Use trigger rules, see [trigger-rules](https://airflow.incubator.apache.org/concepts.html#trigger-rules) on how to use them.
2. Use on_failure_callback and on_success_callback to define what happens if your task fails/succeeds, see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312439/airflow-default-on-failure-callback) or the definitions in the BaseOperator [API Reference](https://airflow.apache.org/concepts.html#baseoperator) (see Parameters -> on_failure_callback,on_success_callback).
3. If you only want the emails to be sent in case of failure or SLA miss and no other task should be executed in that case, define:
   `default_args = {'email': ['some_email_adress'],'email_on_failure': True"}`, airflow will then send an email with the error/sla miss to the defined emails.

Comment: Also, BranchPythonOperator

Comment: Thanks Chris. I did not mention that I'm trying to send a slack message instead of an email.  I should be dynamically able to send this message as "task succeeded", "task failed" & "task Running(sla not met)" . How do I capture these 3 states of task1?

Comment: Well the easiest set up for the default failure and success would be 2 slack operators downstream of task1, one with trigger_rule='all_success' and one with 'all_failed'. Now I've never worked with SLAs, so I don't if the tasks fails if it misses the SLA or if airflow only sends an email. If it fails, you'd have to figure out how to get the information if the failure was caused by the SLA miss or not. If the task fails when the SLA gets missed and you figure out how to get that information from the task_instance, you could probably use jinja templating in the failure slack operator message.