# How we can handle any exception in python script when DAG is running?

Tags: python, airflow

I am new in python and airflow, I have some doubts like How we can handle any exception or how we can create custom exception at the time airflow. some scenarios.

1. if we want to access/read any file but file is not available In case of `filenotfoundexception` how we can handle exception.
2. At the time of Data insertion in any database(postgres,mysql) but Data insertion is not successful how we can handle same problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: in addition to conventional handling of exception (python's try-except blocks), you might also be interested in [`on_failure_callback`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45312439/airflow-default-on-failure-callback)

Answer (score 0):

To create your own exceptions subclass `Exception`:

```
class MyException(Exception):
    pass
```

Note that many times you don't need to do that as an Exception of the needed type already exists in the standard exceptions hierarchy. Just use one of those. See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/exceptions.html) and [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/errors.html).

Protect code where you expect a certain kind of exception to occur within a `try`block:

```
try:
    dangerous_code()

except MyException:
    # do something
    ...
```

If you want you may rise the exception manually:

```
if condition:
    raise MyException
```